# Error during NearDuplicatesDetection 0.2.0 installation

Tags: python, git, ubuntu-13.10, anaconda

I just wanted to install NearDuplicatesDetection 0.2.0 using

pip install git://github.com/parkr/near-dup-detection.git#egg=NearDuplicatesDetection

But I got this error:

```
184, in get_url_rev
url, rev = super(Git, self).get_url_rev()
File ".../anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/vcs/__init__.py", line 124,          
in get_url_rev
assert '+' in self.url, error_message % self.url
AssertionError: Sorry, 'git://github.com/parkr/near-dup-detection.git' is a malformed VCS
url. The format is <vcs>+<protocol>://<url>, e.g. svn+http://myrepo/svn/MyApp#egg=MyApp
```

How can I fix this? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax to combine `git` with `pip` is:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/parkr/near-dup-detection.git#egg=NearDuplicatesDetection
```